# absolutely positioned elements adding scroll on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design

I want to have a page that takes the full height and width of the client window. I want to be able to position divs within the page using position=absolute, with a specified transform. They will be playing cards on a table, so they'll have an x, y, and rotation. This all works great, but on mobile, when one of the absolutely positioned elements goes beyond the boundaries of the parent, the browser adds a scrollbar and lets you scroll to the out-of-bounds elements. I've found that I can clip the rendering of the absolutely positioned elements by using clip-path: inset(0) on the parent, but the mobile page still lets you scroll over to the white part beyond the application. Is there some other way to restrict the viewport to just the body so I can keep my full-page, non-scrolling experience in tact? I don't think overflow:hidden works here because of the absolute positioning.

here's an example. https://ddeklotz-static-page.s3.amazonaws.com/example.html

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="app">
      <div class="square"/>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>



body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.app {
    background-color: red;
    min-height: 100vh;
    clip-path:inset(0);
}

.square {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(330px, 50px) rotate(20deg);
}
```

[image]

Comment: Where can we see this working?

Comment: @AndyHoffman I added a link in the description.

Answer (score 2):

I think I found something that works: I needed to add "user-scalable=0" to my viewport meta tag's content. It looks like before the viewport was zoomed out to show the full extent of the clipped div's bounding region, which isn't what I wanted. Disabling user scaling means we just keep the layout viewport in view, I think.

It looks like I also could have use position:fixed (instead of absolute) to address this, but that would have made the positioning of the divs more difficult (as their parent isn't likely to have the same origin as the viewport).

Comment: This fixed my vertical scrollbar problem, but not the horizontal one. The user still can scroll horizontally to view a part of an absolute positioned element.